# addEventListener keyup Keydown with Keycode not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keycode

```
<input class="inputVal">
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myVal = document.getElementsByClassName('inputVal')[0]; 

    myVal.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        var count = myVal.value;
        console.log(count)
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: define "not working". Do you mean the event handler is not called at all, or it doesn't go into the `if` statement or what?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try bind event to `document` or `window`. If an element is not focusable and is not focused, keyboard events won't dispatch to it, instead they dispatch to document root(`<body>`).

Comment: Very important and useful to remember. Another hint is that if you listen to `keyup`/`keydown` (or other) events on a global object (e.g `document.body`), you can distinguish events originating from a focused element (e.g an `input` tag) and from this global object in your event handler by inspecting the `target` property of the event object. If the event originates from a focused element, `target` will be `!==` your 'global' object (e.g `document.body`).

Comment: @origo Inexplicably helpful answer and comment +1 for each one, especially for beginners such as me, by the bye good comment as for the usage of `stopPropagation()` if you practice the comment.